# Extracting first line from a file if condition matches in a block

Tags: awk, yaml

I have the below file and I need to capture all the hostnames in a single file separated by "," which have Failed: 0 in them

**file.txt:**

```
host1:
   name: sudo something
   name: something
   succeeded: 34
   Failed: 0
host2:
   name: something 123
   succeeded: 12
   Failed: 3
host3:
   name: something 1234
   succeeded: 12
   Failed: 13
host4:
   name: something 1234
   succeeded: 12
   Failed: 0
```

So, the output should be host1, host4. I have tried the below code:

```
awk -F ':' '/:/{host=$1; getline; if($1 !~ /Failed:0/) NR==1{print host}}' file.txt > output.txt
```

Can anyone, advice how to go about it, please? I would prefer to do it in one line command as I need to pass it via Jenkins pipeline.

========================Update===============================

Using **grep - V Name:** my input file looks as below:

host1:

### Summary for host1

Succeeded: 36 (changed=10)

Failed:     0

host4:

### Summary for host4

Succeeded: 36 (changed=10)

Failed:     0

Now, how can I just filter for Failed:  0 cases and get the hostnames?

Comment: host4 doesn't *have* Failed: 0, is that a typo?

Comment: Your YAML is broken, `Failed <n>` not belongs to any host, the indentation is wrong

Comment: fixed the typo, host4 should have failed: 0

Answer (score 2):

OP's input may contain carriage returns (`\r`) so this `awk` should work with both type of line endings (DOS or Unix):

```
awk -v ORS="," -F: '$2 ~ /^\r?$/{host=$1} /^[ \t]*Failed:[ \t]*0/{print host}' file
```

Note that there will be a trailing comma instead of ending line break here. In case it matters use:

```
awk -v ORS="," -F: '$2 ~ /^\r?$/{host=$1} /^[ \t]*Failed:v0/{print host}' file | 
sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

Comment: for some wired reason i'm getting a blank output. See the updated section above. I have filtered out all Name: case now the file structure is bit changed. Any idea, what can be done next?

Comment: Anubhava, i tried this: awk -v ORS="," -F: '$2 ~ /^\r?$/{host=$1} /^[ \t]*Failed: 0/{print host}' newjenkinsfeed.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/' > Anubhava.txt getting a blank file

Comment: There is a long space between Failed and zero, something like Failed:             0. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Can you try: `awk -v ORS="," -F: '$2 ~ /^\r?$/{host=$1} /^[ \t]*Failed:[ \t]*0/{print host}' file`

Answer (score 1):

could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=":"
}
/host/{
  ho=$1
  next
}
ho && /Failed: 0/{
  total=(total?total",":"")ho
  ho=""
}
END{
  if(total){
    print total
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                               ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=":"                             ##Setting field sep as : here.
}
/host/{                              ##Checking condition if host is in line.
  ho=$1                              ##Setting ho variable to $1 here.
  next                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
ho && /Failed: 0/{                   ##Checking if ho is SET and Failed: 0 is found in line.
  total=(total?total",":"")ho        ##Creating total variable and keep on adding values in it.
  ho=""                              ##Nullifying ho here.
}
END{                                 ##Starting END block of this specific progra here.
  if(total){                         ##Checking if total is NOT NULL.
    print total                      ##Printing total variable here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

As per OP request additional one liner form of above:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {gsub(/\r/,"")} /host/{ho=$1;next} ho && /Failed: 0/{total=(total?total",":"")ho;ho=""} END{if(total){print total}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh, I can't pass the block inside my pipeline. Can you please help with a one liner?

Comment: @AmitPattnaik, ok added that now, but in my humble opinion experts wouldn't advice to write long one liners better to use non-one liner form solutions please.

Comment: i'm getting the below error: awk: cmd. line:1: error: attempt to use non-function `total' in function call

Comment: @AmitPattnaik, did my code work for you? Kindly do lemme know.

Comment: RavinderSingh, i'm getting the below error: awk: cmd. line:1: error: attempt to use non-function `total' in function call. Please see the updated section. Now i have remove all Name: rows using grep -v and i got a new file now. Can you suggest how can i just get the host name for Failed: 0 cases in a file separated by ","

Comment: @AmitPattnaik, solutions are tested and they worked fine. Did you check my non-one liner solutions all worked for me lemme know.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/:$/{h=$1; sub(/:/,"",h)} /Failed: 0/{print h}' file1 | paste -sd,
host1,host4
```

note that your host4 normally should not appear in the list.  This is after
`sed -i '$s/13/0/' file`

I guess it can be simplified as suggested

```
$ awk -F: '$2==""{h=$1} /Failed: 0/{print h}' file1 | paste -sd,
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'm not getting the required output. when i tried: awk '/:$/{h=$1; sub(/:/,"",h)} /Failed: 0/{print h}' jenkinsfeed.txt | paste -sd, i get blank output. Am i missing anything?

Comment: is the data sourced from windows/dos? If so either run `dos2unix` or need to incorporate dos/windows linefeed/newline.

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML with the good indentation:

```
host1:
   name: sudo something
   name: something
   succeeded: 34
   Failed: 0
host2:
   name: something 123
   succeeded: 12
   Failed: 3
host3:
   name: something 1234
   succeeded: 12
   Failed: 13
host4:
   name: something 1234
   succeeded: 12
   Failed: 13
```

Now with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), we can properly parse the YAML :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $conf_file = "conf.yaml";   

use strict; use warnings;
use YAML::AppConfig;

my $conf = YAML::AppConfig->new(file => $conf_file) or die;

foreach my $host (keys %{$conf->{config}}) {
    print $host if $conf->{config}->{$host}->{"Failed"} == 0;
}
```

### Output

```
host1
host4
```

This is the hosts with `Failed 0`

Comment: Thanks, you are right that the correct format. However, I'm looking for a one-liner awk/sed based solution as I need to pass it through a pipeline.

Comment: I don't see the need to not use **a proper YAML parser**. You can even pipe it like any other tools: `perl script.pl | pipeline`